# Copy all outgoing emails, including emails created by BCC

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

We are using Office 365, including Exchange 365 hosted on the cloud.  I created a mail flow rule to copy all emails to a mailbox for archiving purposes.  We use this to quantify and report on contact activity between brokers and our clients.
Unfortunately, I am not getting any of the emails created because of a BCC.  If I send an email with 1 recipient and 5 BCC recipients, the 5 copies sent to the BCC recipients never hit the archive.

The creation of the BCC emails by the server seems to work outside my mail flow rule.  Is there any way I can capture copies of the emails being created by the BCC?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BCC every incoming and outgoing e-mail in Microsoft Exchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/575814/bcc-every-incoming-and-outgoing-e-mail-in-microsoft-exchange)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate.  The link you posted shows how to create a rule like the one I am currently using.  I am asking how to capture emails being created by Exchange in response to an outgoing email with BCCs.  The rule created, like the one in your link, only gets the original email in the archive account, none of the emails created and sent because of the BCC.

Comment: Can you show your rule?

Comment: Updated to show the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mail flow rules, use Journaling in the Exchange admin center. Journal reports cannot be delivered to an internal Office 365 mailbox, or an external account that is already associated for password recovery. So if you don't have an on-premises Exchange server, you may want to create a Gmail account or similar before you get started.

Another prerequisite to creating journaling rules is that you'll need to assign an internal email address to have your undeliverable journal reports delivered to.  It's best to use this mailbox only for these reports.  You can create a shared mailbox for this purpose and it won't cost you anything. Once you've got an internal mailbox for undeliverable reports and an external mailbox for the actual journaling.

From EAC, select `compliance management` --> `journal rules`

Just above the "+" there's a line that reads `Send undeliverable journal reports to: Select address` Click the "Select address" link and use your internal mailbox as the target.

Next, click the "+" to add a new rule. These are the fields available:

- `Send journal reports to:` - must be an external or on-premises
  Exchange mailbox
- `Name` - optional field
- `If the message is sent to or received from...` - specify a user, a group, or all messages
- `Journal the following messages...` - choose internal, external, or all messages

Save your journaling rule, and you're good to go. One thing to be aware of: O365 has a limit of 10 journaling rules.

Comment: TY very thorough, I will try it tomorrow with a BCC test and let you know.